# Vim Plug-ins for debugging Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby, debugging, vim, macvim, ruby-2.0

I have seen a handful of options for running a Ruby debugger within Vim, including some great answers on StackOverflow.  However, most of these appear to address Ruby 1.8 or 1.9.2, and it's not clear how to get a debugger running in Vim with Ruby 2.0.0.

The most up-to-date seems to be https://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger .  Thanks to some answers here on SO I've been able to get a Rails server running under this plug-in.  However, setting a breakpoint seems to have no effect: the code just completes without breaking.

I'm using MacVim from homebrew, and it answers to having Ruby enabled.

Am I missing some other plug-ins or gems?

What set of Vim plug-ins and Ruby gems are required to get a good debugging experience in Vim (especially on Mac OS X Lion)?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0 was released, what? Two weeks ago? Three? Do you seriously think that everybody and every plugin was updated in the mean time? You should get in touch with atashov to see if something can be done. I think that you will get better results that way.

Comment: "To see if something can be done"? How about "to see if there is a way help"?

Comment: Debuggers are not Ruby scripts. They are very tightly coupled to an interpreter and when the interpreter gets updated things can break. Developers learn to wait for the interpreter to update, then make their changes. Trying to release in parallel doesn't work because last minute changes in the version being released can break lots of code. So be patient, it will happen when it happens. Your 1.9.3 Ruby and debugger work fine. And maybe you should look into using Pry as a debugger in the interim?

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan.  I'll check into Pry.  I'm not sure that I have the debugger working even with 1.9.3, so it seemed prudent to ask what other gems I might be missing.